# Showing dialog by Dialog API disables cell editing

Tags: excel, office-js

In my Excel Add-In, I use the Dialog API to show messages to the user. The dialog is shown and closed without any problem or error thrown.

When the dialog is closed, the user cannot edit cells in the sheet by a simple click in the cell and writing.

If the user double click some cell, this functionality is back again (for all cells).

Here is the code controlling the dialog:

```js
var app = (function (app) {
    var dialog;

    // Show dialog
    app.showNotification = function (header, text) {
        if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('DialogApi', 1.1)) {
            var dialogUrl = window.location.href.substring(0,
                    window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) +
                "AppMessage.html?msg=" + text + "&title=" + header;

            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogUrl, {
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    displayInIframe: true
                },
                function (asyncResult) {
                    dialog = asyncResult.value;
                    dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,
                        processMessage);
                });
        }
    };

    function processMessage(arg) {
        if (arg.message == "close")
            dialog.close();
    }

    return app;
})(app || {});
```

and the dialog code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css">
    <script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <span class="ms-font-xl ms-fontWeight-semibold" id="titleMain"></span>
    <p class="ms-font-m" id="body"></p>
    <button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" style="position:fixed;bottom:10px;right:10px;" onclick="closeDialog();">
              <span class="ms-Button-label">OK</span>
          </button>
    <script src="appMessage.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and here is the `appMessage.js` content

```js
var urlParams;

Office.initialize = function () {};

//avoiding the usage of jquery in this small page
window.$ = function (selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
};

function closeDialog() {
    Office.context.ui.messageParent("close");
}

(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl = /\+/g, // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) {
            return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " "));
        },
        query = window.location.search.substring(1);

    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
        urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);

    $("#titleMain").innerHTML = urlParams["title"];
    $("#body").innerHTML = urlParams["msg"];
})();
```

What can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You may be getting an error and not realize it. If you add an event handler for `Office.EventType.DialogErrorReceived` you'll be able to see if any errors are surfacing from the dialog: see [this page for instructions](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/93bf3d5c77466880d957bdd666c40bfee4ee5b40/docs/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins.md#errors-and-events-in-the-dialog-window).

Comment: Does the behavior change if the user closes the dialog box (hits the `x`) vs. you closing it from the parent?

Comment: No change, it behaves equally. I don's see my previous comment above, so I'm not sure I sent it - so, just to be sure - I also added the event handler for exceptions according to your suggestions, but no exception occurred.

Comment: I suspect something larger is going on then. When the user clicks the `x`, it should surface via the `DialogEventReceived` as `12006` in the `arg.error` property.

Comment: 'something larger' on my side or library side?

Comment: Given that I'm not able to replicate this, it is hard to tell. Its strange that you're able to get a `DialogMessage` but not a `DialogEvent`.